# How to fix: 'TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable in scipy fmin_bfgs

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, optimization, scipy, callable-object

I'm trying to solve Andrew NG's course week 3 assignment in Python instead of matlab, and I found out that fmin_bfgs is similarly equal to fminunc in the ex2.m file

The problem is, when I try to enter the cost function and the function that computes gradients into fmin_bfgs it returns a traceback saying that:
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable.
I'm having a hard time trying to debug the problem so any help would be appreciated

```
# code that produces the error:

results = opt.fmin_bfgs(costFunction.cost_function(weights, data_input, desired_output), weights,
                        fprime=costFunction.compute_grad(weights, data_input, desired_output), maxiter=400)

#the costFunction module:

import numpy as np
import sigmoid


def cost_function(theta, x, y):
    size = np.shape(x)
    z = np.dot(x, theta)
    h = sigmoid.sigmoid(z)
    j = (1 / size[0]) * (np.dot(-y, np.log(h)) - np.dot((1 - y), np.log(1 - h)))
    return j


def compute_grad(theta, x, y):
    size = np.shape(x)
    z = np.dot(x, theta)
    h = sigmoid.sigmoid(z)
    error = np.subtract(h, y)
    grad = (1 / size[0]) * np.dot(np.transpose(error), x)
    return grad
```

Comment: The first argument to the `fmin_bfgs` is supposed to be a function, not the value produced by running that function.  `fmin_bfgs` provides various `theta` values to this function.  Same goes for the `fprime` function.  You need to read the docs and test the examples.

Comment: I read what to do and now I'm trying to call the function with this line instead:
results = opt.fmin_bfgs(costFunction.cost_function, weights,
                        fprime=costFunction.compute_grad, maxiter=400)
but it gives errors that these functions that are called require positional arguments..
I'm sorry If I'm asking too much

Comment: What's the relationship between `theta, x, y` and `weights`?  `fmin_bfgs` calls your functions with one iteration variable (may be an array) and any variables that you provide via the `args` **tuple**.

Comment: Well I think I just didn't figure out about passing the arguments of `f` and `fprime` in the `args` tuple, you made it clear to me so thank you very much!